# Add static and dynamic values to ComboBox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to add 'All' option on top of other records fetched from database shown in dropdownlist.Any ideas on how to do this in vb.net 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Think around the problem. Instead of adding the item to the combobox, add the item to the dynamic datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Even in VS 2005 the [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property was available. So you can add this item programmatically from codebehind or declaratively on aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList
    runat="server"
    ID="DropDownList1"
    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
>
            <asp:ListItem
                Enabled="True"
                Selected="True"
                Text="All"
                Value="0"
            />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now all your databound items are appended automatically and the first item will not be removed.

Comment: does not work! getting error - AppendDataBoundItems is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox ...this is not supported in vb.net i guess! Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @gigglingwonder: Sorry, i thought that you were using ASP.NET not Winforms. I don't delete my answer since it might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Came across AppendDataBoundItems on many forums! but this works only for asp.net! need something similar on vb.net asap!

Comment: @gigglingwonder: I've edited your question to clarify your requirement. Btw, _asap_ is a word that is not welcome on SO. People try to help you freely, so no need to hurry them.

Answer (score 0):

below worked for me!

Add a new row to datasource

```
    Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables("cusPracticeLocation").NewRow
    'Add some data to it
    dr(0) = 0
    dr(1) = "All"
    ds.Tables("cusPracticeLocation").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)
```